# How do you get an application to close itself?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-3.5

How do I get an application to close itself?

At the moment, I have the following:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load()
    'do something first

    Me.Dispose()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

When I double click the .exe, the application seems to work fine, but I can still see an instance of it in the Windows Task Manager Processes tab.

How do I get it to close itself properly?

Comment: You want it to act like a virus(not being able to spot at the task manager)?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg, No sorry.  I want it in the task manager while it's running, then once it's closed i.e. `me.dispose()` and `me.close()`, it shouldn't appear in the task manager.  At the moment, it stays in the task manager.  It doesn't seem to close properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
Me.dispose()
Me.close()
```

Interchange the two

```
Me.close()
Me.dispose()
```

and

`Application.exit()`

should work as well

Comment: Objects don't need to be disposed more than one time, use just me.close or me.dispose, but not both. A perform of a code analysis feature in VisualStudio will alert about that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Application.Exit()?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Private Sub ButtonClose_Click() 
    Application.Exit

    End Sub
```